# AttributeError: module 'sass' has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: sass, odoo, libsass

I am trying to install odoo12 but getting this error like
AttributeError: module 'sass' has no attribute 'compile'.

I installed libsass python library which is required for odoo12 after installing thar error happened

please, anyone help.

Comment: Odoo 12? from where did you get it? since have not been release it yet, until the next month.

Comment: @AxelMendoza you can use saas-11.5 if you want Odoo 12. Or master, but this is not advised.

Comment: @switch87 So it's not Odoo 12 what you are testing, it's saas-11.5

Comment: saas-11.5 is the first v12 freeze for the Odoo saas servers, because Odoo community is open source you can already download it. Enterprise is not available yet.
Master is a rolling release, so you should not use it, it has breaking changes on the database tables from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

try doing `pip freeze | grep sass` if the output lists the sass module next to libsass this is the problem. removing sass (and optionally reinstalling libsass) should fix the problem.